# "usages" of except "for" and "times"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When I emailed somebody my weekly schedule, I wrote:

I'm free except **for** the following **times**: MWF 4-5pm; TR 8-9am; F 10-12am.

I'm not sure about the usage (or **usages**?) of the above bold words: shall I keep "for" or not? Shall I use "times" or "time slots" or "time periods"?

Comment: The simplest way: “I'm free except: MWF 4–5pm”, etc.

Comment: The phrase _time slots_ tends to be used only when referring to a schedule with predefined periods that need to be filled in. Like the times of TV network broadcasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the sentence is fine with or without "for", although I prefer it with. You could also use "at" instead of "for". "times" is perfect; while the other variants you give are not incorrect, they feel a little more stilted to me.